# Headers in Retrofit with Android

Tags: android, header, retrofit

I've been reading about Retrofit and I got to the point of Headers and I don't know if I understood them too well. In the course I'm doing it uses them to establish an authentication with a user created in the backend and a database and it does it in two different ways:

```
private WebServiceBA() {

    loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

    httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(chain -> {

       Request original = chain.request();
       Request.Builder requestBuild = original
               .newBuilder()
               .addHeader("Authorization", AUTH_USER)
               .method(original.method(), original.body());
       Request request = requestBuild.build();
       return chain.proceed(request);
   });

   retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(BASE_URL_BA)
               .client(httpClientBuilder.build())
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .build();
  }
```

In this first form I understand that the Header is passing through code but I don't understand the `.method(original.method(), original.body());`. And in this one it's passing it through the Retrofit call itself:

```
@GET("/todos_profesores_admin")
Call<List<ProfesorBA>> listAllProfesorAdmin(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader);
```

I don't understand if "Authorization" is something that should be like that since it's in the backend or it's a way to call it in the code.

I suppose that by doing it in the call, in this case we have more freedom since we pass him the users that we want, but what other things can we send through the Header of a Retrofit call or how far does its usefulness extend? Thank you very much.